# ankle weights for glutes

Tags: workout, bodyweight-exercises, resistance, glutes

i've been reading about ankle weights. And i was wondering if they really help for glute exercise. Also, if my thighs are gonna be bigger. If you have an experience, please, share!

Comment: What do you plan on doing with these ankle weights? What exercises in particular?

Answer (score 1):

Ankle weights are mainly useful for abs by making Toes to bar, L-sits, and Hollow holds harder, they can also be used for glutes and hamstrings (Reverse hyperextensions, and Arch holds) and if you are there, you can also make your handstand pushups harder with them

Answer (score 0):

Simply wearing ankle weights will do nothing for your glutes.  If you perform an exercise with them, like [this](https://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/main/popup/name/glute-kickback/), then you will target your glutes, and not your thighs.

Deep barbell or goblet squats with a wide stance or walking lunges with dumbbells are great glue exercises.  They will tone your legs, and not add to much size.

Comment: "They will tone your legs, and not add to much size."  What does that mean, physiologically/anatomically?  It sounds pseudo-scientific.

Comment: I agree-- I only say this because "to tone" is a very common phrase.  When people say "I want to tone my legs," they mean "I want my legs to be firm and defined."  In *every* case, these results can only be obtained by shedding fat, not by simply lifting weights.  So I try to use a common phrase to emphasize that squats won't primary target the legs, like a leg extension would for instance.

Comment: Aha, fair enough!